How to Use Theme Provider When Using CSS Method in Emotion/React
const headerStyle = css`
  margin: ${({theme}) => theme.????}
`;

const Header = styled.header<{ isActive: boolean }>`
  max-width: ${({ theme }) => theme.sizes.mobile};
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  ${({ theme }) => css`
    div {
      padding: ${theme.sizes.padding};
    }
  `}
`;

import '@emotion/react';

import theme from '../styles/theme';

type ThemeType = typeof theme;

declare module '@emotion/react' {
  export interface Theme extends ThemeType {}
}

What is the way to use the theme provided by the Theme Provider when using the CSS method instead of styled in Emotion? I have correctly sent an object from the ThemeProvider and declared the types through emotion.d.ts, but it seems that the CSS literal method cannot reference the theme. Also, how can I pass props?
